# Memory Usage in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, row

I have been thinking about database design lately and I have the following question:

When a type, say a varchar(max), is set for a column is 2GB of space set aside every time a row is inserted?

Or is the space allocated on the server equal to the amount of data in the column?

Thanks!

Comment: It is really bad idea to store that huge data in database. Use file system for that.

Comment: Ok, lets say a varchar(200)...the question doesn't change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `varchar` data type in SQL Server and elsewhere means roughly variable-length character data. The `max` or any other constant value represents its upper bound and not its absolute size. So your latter observation is correct:

> the space allocated on the server
>   equal to the amount of data in the
>   column

Now, if you define something like `char(200)` (notice the lack of var in front of char there) then yes, 200 characters are allocated regardless of how much data (up to 200 chars) you store in that field. The [maximum upper bound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) for the `char` data type is 8000, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Of course not :)

`Varchar(max)` is a <strike>**bastardised**</strike> hybrid data type <strike>(if you do not mind me being a bit frank)</strike>:

- It is stored with the rest of the columns in the row if total row length does not exceed **8KB limit**
- Otherwise stored as a blob. A blob (TEXT,IMAGE) takes as much as its length.

Comment: Perhaps Hybrid is better than bastardised? ;)

Comment: To be honest, I do not like `varchar(max)`. It is for lazy database designers who cannot figure out how much storage they need.

Comment: Generally. In this case, I will be using the database to store stack traces, and it will have a trigger that will delete rows after a certain number of rows are inserted, so memory will be managed quite carefully. It is also a separate database on a separate server for dev-only use.

Comment: @badpanda **Sorry I did not mean you are one.** Obviously you are being careful about usage. But I would suggest going for a precise VARCHAR or TEXT if you can.

Comment: @Aliostad. Just out of curiosity, if you're designing SO's Post table would you use a Blob or a varchar(max)?

Comment: @Aliostad - RE: "lazy database designers" are you suggesting people should use deprecated types instead such as `text` or `image`? The obvious use case for it is storing data that might be >8000 bytes.

Comment: **OK guys hold fire** - I did not mean to offend anyone and `VARCHAR(MAX)` can also have its place in certain circumstances. But I have seen it too often that someone declares all string fields as `VARCHAR(MAX)`